# Based on the input field i need to autoselect the checkbox in the table in angular

Tags: angular

i have a  requirement where if i give 2 in the input field , i need to autoselect the matcheckbox in the another table.like in the below picture if im enter in the input field based on that need to autoselec the checkboxes.

```html
<mat-form-field fxFlex="45">
   <input fxFlex matInput placeholder="Enter Total Damage Count"
        formControlName="count" id="count" type="number" 
       class="form-control" required>
</mat-form-field>

<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i =index"> 
   <mat-checkbox class="example-margin" #damageCheckBox   [checked]="element.damage"  
     [ngClass]="(element.isDamage)? 'mat-checkbox-checked':''"
     (change)="addDamaged(element.id ,i)">Is Damaged</mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

[image: Image of table]

Comment: It will not hurt use punctuations and use `I` instead of `i`, `I am` instead of `im`.  If you show that you have taken your time to frame your question, then, it will show that you respect the time of many SO users who are here to help by answering those questions.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using the `valueChanges` observable in the formGroup (or formControl) that contains the input.

In the component class you should have a FormGroup instance, so with the following code you can react to the changes in the form.

```
myForm.get('count').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
   if (value === 2) {
       // Autoselect the checkboxes
    }
});
```

Then, to update the checkboxes, you should change the `damage` flag of all the items  to true and force the table to re-render the new changes. As it is a MatTable, you can do it by using the [renderRows](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api) method or just by assigning a fresh copy of your array to the source of the table.

Comment: autoSelect(){
    this.secondFormGroup.get('count').value;
    console.log( this.secondFormGroup.get('count').value);
    if(this.totalMaterialList.replicate==true){
      console.log('true');
      
    }
    else{
      console.log('false');
      
    }
  
    this is the method i wrote so i can able to read the value whatever im entering in the input field ,but i dont know how to write the logic  based on the value i need to autoselect ,For eg  if i enter 3 checkboxes have to autoselect remaining have to be diasabled check

Comment: ,Hi im using the method where i acn able to read the value of the input field when i enter ,but i dont how to write the logic , based on the count i need to autoselect checkboxes ,remaining need to be disabledcheckbox.